# Execução automática de método

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Estou com um classe x que precisa executar um método y uma vez por dia. Entretanto, como fazer isto em PHP Orientado a objeto?

P.S: Em PHP estruturado, utilizava crontab ou fcron para programar que uma determinada URL fosse executada em determinado horário. Naquele script, colocava as modificações necessárias.

Answer (score 2):

Basta apontar nessa URL agendada um arquivo com a chamada do método dessa classe

Arquivo Classe:

```
<?php

// path/minhaClasse.php

class minhaClasse{
    public function meuMetodo($parametro){
        // Faz alguma coisa
    }

    public static function meuMetodoEstatico($parametro){
        // Roda o mesmo método, porém de forma estática
        return $this->meuMetodo($parametro);
    }
}
```

Arquivo com a chamada da classe

```
<?php
require "path/minhaClasse.php";

$classe = new minhaClasse();
$classe->meuMetodo('parametro');
```

Ou é possível utilizar uma chamada estática:

```
<?php
require "path/minhaClasse.php";

\minhaClasse::meuMetodoEstatico('parametro');
```

Answer (score 1):

Você continuará tendo que executar o cron para agendar a chamada do php, pois o php depende de uma requisição para ser interpretado.

Você pode escrever uma classe em PHP e usar os métodos [class_exists](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.class-exists.php) para verificar se a classe **x** existe, se existir você cria uma instância dela e usa o método, [method_exists](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.function-exists.php) para verificar se o método **y** existe. Se existir, você executa o método.

Você pode usar o php como script para chamar ele em terminal via cli, basta você informar que o interpretador de textos a ser usado é o php, adicionando uma instrução semelhante a instrução a seguir ao inicio do arquivo, (falo semelhante, pois ela deve ter o caminho do seu interpretador de php, se não souber onde encontrar pode digitar no console whereis php, que será exibido).

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php
```

Estou assumindo que esteja usando linux.

Answer (score 0):

Uma maneira pouco usual de resolver seu problema sem usar o `CRON` seria com um script que rodasse um loop infinito com o seguinte conteúdo (ou algo do tipo):

```
<?php

while(true){
    checkRemoteSite();
    updateYourDB();
    sleep(6000);
}
```